# Reshaping tensor 2d to 1d

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

```
tensor([[17,  0],
        [93,  0],
        [0,  0],
        [21,  0],
        [19,  0])
```

I want to remove 0 from this tensor, which is a two-dimensional array, and make it a one-dimensional array.

How can I make this tensor with the tensor below?

```
tensor([[17],
        [93],
        [0],
        [21],
        [19])
```

When using the code below, there is a problem that the existing zero disappears.
How should I fix this?

```
x = x.flatten()
x = x[x!=0]
x = np.reshape(x, ( -1, x.shape[0] ))
```

array([[17, 93, 21, 19]])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use slicing to index the `0` column

```
import torch

t = torch.tensor(
      [[17,  0],
       [93,  0],
       [0,  0],
       [21,  0],
       [19,  0]]
    )

print(t[:,0])
```

Output

```
tensor([17, 93,  0, 21, 19])
```

And if you want to keep it a 2D array then you can use `numpy.reshape`

```
import torch
import numpy as np

t = torch.tensor(
      [[17,  0],
       [93,  0],
       [0,  0],
       [21,  0],
       [19,  0]]
    )

print(np.reshape(t[:,0], (-1, 1)))
```

Output

```
array([[17],
       [93],
       [ 0],
       [21],
       [19]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thanks to you, I solved the problem. But is there any solution without using tensorflow?

Comment: I updated my answer to replace `tensorflow` with `pytorch`, let me know if that is not the library you are using.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm using a torch. I haven't seen the code you wrote using only a torch above. Thank you.

Comment: To slice a column tensor without reshaping `t[:, 0:1]`